# Faster way to create structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to create structure like this in Python 3?

```
data = {0: (X, X), 1:(X1, X1), 2:(X2, X2), N:(Xn, Xn)}
```

in faster way?

Here 0..N is a Keys, and (X, X)...(Xn, Xn) - variables

Comment: What are `X` and `X1` and `X2` and `Xn`? Are you saying you literally have n variables named `X1` through `Xn`?

Comment: Faster in which sense? Fewer keystrokes, shorter runtime?

Comment: I think he means faster, as in instead of typing it out manually? If I am not misunderstanding the question, this really isn't a coding question. Perhaps you should look into text editors like Sublime-Text. You can bulk edit multiple lines simultaneously.

Comment: @Aran-Fey X1...Xn ... Xn - this is variables. Numbers will placed instead of this.

Comment: @bereal Shorter runtime

Comment: @Alex then I guess it's fine as it is.

Comment: Why on earth are you optimizing the runtime of a dict literal? Do you have *any* reason to believe that *this* is what's slowing down your code?

Comment: If you really mean it, you may want to look at `__slots__` or `namedtuple` or `@dataclass`. But I think you don't need to optimize the creation of a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how are your `Xn` variables (in a list for instance), you can use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
data = {i: (x, x) for i, x in enumerate(list_xs)}
```